# Windows 7 and corrupted files

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I have brought a new PC and installed Windows 7 86_64 on it, but I keep getting corrupted files.
Every time I download a RAR / ZIP file or any kind of archive from the Internet I get this problem.
I don't think it is related to my Internet connection since it works just fine on any other computer.

I'm wondering if it can be coming from the hardware, the [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive), the RAM or the CPU?

```
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 965 3.4 GHz BLACK SKT AM3 L2/L3 8 MB 12
RAM: CORSAIR DDR3, 1333 MHZ 4 GB 2X240 DIMM, UNBUFFERED
SSD: SSD SAMSUNG 64 GB MLC - MMCRE64G5MPP
GPU: ATI HD4890 1GO GDDR5 PCIe
```

For example, if I download a torrent I'll have to re-check it at the end and download the missing blocks, it happens all the time.

Comment: umm, which version did you actually install? x86 or x64? :)

Comment: I installed the version for 64 bits cpu's

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of random problems such as this is bad or failing memory.

The first thing I would do is download [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org) and do a full scan of your system.

Comment: Plus, run it for a day or more, 1 or 2 passes just isn't enough; we usually aim for 72-hours of continual MemTesting before we decide the RAM is 'probably' OK.  Over the years I've seen lots of RAM work fine until the 3rd day of testing.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser are you using? Is this limited to archives only or are other files such as executables corrupted as well?

There is a variety of options:

1. try a different browser
2. use a download manager or a command line download utility such as **[Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)**.
3. download via FTP where applicable.

Comment: I'm using google chrome, but this problem does happen with anything else, bittorrent clients, software installers using internet connection, anything:)

Comment: try 7-Zip x64: http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: same problem, for example with the Eve online installer that uses 7-zip installer I always get CRC errors

Comment: go and test your system memory as Wil suggests.

Answer (score 1):

If it was something as integral as RAM or your SSD HDD, I would expect to be seeing system lockups or BSODs from experience.  I'm more inclined to think that you have either a corrupted network stack or a faulty network card at play.

Firstly, ensure you have the latest drivers installed for your network card from your computer manufacturer's website.

Secondly, I would suggest resetting the network stack.

1. Click `Start`
2. Type `CMD` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (runs the command prompt elevated)
3. Type `netsh winsock reset` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type `netsh int ip reset` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Restart.

Do you have a spare network card or maybe wireless functionality at home to be able to use a wireless USB stick instead - to rule out your network card as the cause?

Comment: This was the problem for me. I was using a USB network adapter, and Windows had decided to use a driver other than the one from the manufacturer. I downloaded the latest driver from the manufacturer and the corrupted .zip downloads seemed to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the archive utility you are using (WinZip, WinRar, etc) is a version that is 64 bit compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any anti-virus running try disabling (or better, temporarily uninstalling) it and see if that affect it (hoepfully stopping the CRCs).  I know certain AV packages have had similar complaints recently with some versions.

If you havn't already, try running a "CHKDSK /R" against the hard drive - this will take a while, but it checks/remaps the blank areas as well, which is where things you download will try and write themselves. :)